# Liquid error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Tags: adxstudio-portals

I am facing this error during AdxStudio in Liquid Web Templates.

**Liquid error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.**

My code is follow:

```
<div>Posts count: {{website.forums[1].threads[0].posts.post_count}}</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this:**

Count Specific forum posts:

```
<div>Posts count: {{website.forums[1].post_count}}</div>
```

Count specific forum,s specific threads count:

```
<div>Posts count: {{website.forums[1].threads.all[0].post_count}}</div>
```